# unable to install phone gap in windows 7 using npm

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins

i am new to phone gap. i am trying to install phone gap in my windows 7 machine.

I tried installing in ubuntu and failed several times. therefore i thought of installing it in windows.

I installed node js successfully

then i try to install phone gap using `npm install -g phonegap`

it never works for me

[image]

can some one help me to install phone gap using npm

Comment: Do you have `git` installed on your PC? Refer Official guide here - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html

Comment: use following command npm install -g cordova